# Crontab schedule every two week

Tags: bash, cron

There is a question happened this week on my crontab job.
It's be set as below and works normal every two weeks until now.

```
10 06 * * 1 test $(($(date +\%W)\%2)) -eq 0 && echo 'test' > /tmp/test.log
```

The problem is

> $(($(date +\%W)\%2)) would be 08, over 7 in February.

And it will show error message if you run in bash: value too great for base (error token is "08").

There is ***also not working*** when I try to revise it for forcing decimal base purpose :

```
10 06 * * 1 test $((10#$(date +\%W)\%2)) -eq 0 && echo 'test' > /tmp/test.log
```

Does someone know how to solve this issue? 
Many thanks.

Comment: The issue here is that `+%W` pads zero in the `date` output which is translated as octal digits. Replace it with `+%-W` to prevent zero padding. Example: `date +%W` outputs `08` while `date +%-W` outputs `8`. The first output is assumed octal while second output is decimal.

Comment: Syntax `$((...))` and `10#...`  are *bashisms* aka. `bash` specific features. `cron` is not `bash`.  That's one of the reason for wich you will prefer to build your own script.

Comment: Thanks everyone! It works normally when following alvits's suggestion.  In man page of date , it shows:" By default, date pads numeric fields with zero. The following option flags may follow %", includes hyphen(do not pad the field).

Answer (score 1):

Every two week at midnight

```
   0 0 */15 * * echo 'test'  > tmp.txt


Your cron job will be run at: (5 times displayed)

2016-03-15 00:00:00 UTC
2016-03-30 00:00:00 UTC
2016-04-15 00:00:00 UTC
2016-04-30 00:00:00 UTC
2016-05-15 00:00:00 UTC
```

Comment: This won't ensure **every two weeks** as requested! see my answer

Answer (score 1):

### Make condition in your script

The use of `%` sign is discouraged in crontab!

To ensure having jod started on ***monday***, every two weeks you've better to create a small script.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" == "-f" ] ;then # use "-f" switch to force execution on odd weeks
    shift
else
    printf -v d '%(%W)T' -1
    ((10#$d%2)) || exit 0  # stop here if odd week
fi

printf "Real job begin at %(%c)T, there...\n" -1
```

This could be shortened to one single line:

```
#!/bin/bash
[ "$1" == "-f" ]&&shift||{ printf -v d '%(%W)T' -1;((10#$d%2))||exit;}
```

So you could add standard lines in  your crontab:

```
10 06 * * 1 path/to/myScript > /tmp/test.log
```

#### Sample: year 2016

```
date -d 2016-1-4\ 10:06  +%s
1451898360
for i in {0..52};do
    printf -v d '%(%W)T' $((c=i*7*86400+1451898360))
    ((10#$d%2)) && printf "%(%a %d %b, week: %W)T\n" $c
  done | cat -n
     1  Mon 04 Jan, week: 01
     2  Mon 18 Jan, week: 03
     3  Mon 01 Feb, week: 05
     4  Mon 15 Feb, week: 07
     5  Mon 29 Feb, week: 09
     6  Mon 14 Mar, week: 11
     7  Mon 28 Mar, week: 13
     8  Mon 11 Apr, week: 15
     9  Mon 25 Apr, week: 17
    10  Mon 09 May, week: 19
    11  Mon 23 May, week: 21
    12  Mon 06 Jun, week: 23
    13  Mon 20 Jun, week: 25
    14  Mon 04 Jul, week: 27
    15  Mon 18 Jul, week: 29
    16  Mon 01 Aug, week: 31
    17  Mon 15 Aug, week: 33
    18  Mon 29 Aug, week: 35
    19  Mon 12 Sep, week: 37
    20  Mon 26 Sep, week: 39
    21  Mon 10 Oct, week: 41
    22  Mon 24 Oct, week: 43
    23  Mon 07 Nov, week: 45
    24  Mon 21 Nov, week: 47
    25  Mon 05 Dec, week: 49
    26  Mon 19 Dec, week: 51
    27  Mon 02 Jan, week: 01
```

For comparission with idea of using ***15th and 30th*** each months:

```
for i in {1..12}/{15,30};do
    date -d '2016/'$i +'%a %d %b, week: %W' 2>/dev/null
  done | cat -n
 1  Fri 15 Jan, week: 02
 2  Sat 30 Jan, week: 04
 3  Mon 15 Feb, week: 07
 4  Tue 15 Mar, week: 11
 5  Wed 30 Mar, week: 13
 6  Fri 15 Apr, week: 15
 7  Sat 30 Apr, week: 17
 8  Sun 15 May, week: 19
 9  Mon 30 May, week: 22
10  Wed 15 Jun, week: 24
11  Thu 30 Jun, week: 26
12  Fri 15 Jul, week: 28
13  Sat 30 Jul, week: 30
14  Mon 15 Aug, week: 33
15  Tue 30 Aug, week: 35
16  Thu 15 Sep, week: 37
17  Fri 30 Sep, week: 39
18  Sat 15 Oct, week: 41
19  Sun 30 Oct, week: 43
20  Tue 15 Nov, week: 46
21  Wed 30 Nov, week: 48
22  Thu 15 Dec, week: 50
23  Fri 30 Dec, week: 52
```

As you could see, there miss one operation on weeks: 6, 9, 10, 21, 32 and 45. At least there is 3 operation less in one year.

Comment: Hi, Hauri, your script can control more detail than what I made, it's amazing!
But it's my weaknesses to understand the code, would you please to explain it?
    1. date -d 2016-1-4\ 10:06  +%s  --> Why it needs back slash to avoid error?
    2. Below's code only known for me are printf -v is with variable and $() stores the variable.
    printf -v d '%(%W)T' $((c=i*7*86400+1451898360))
    ((10#$d%2)) && printf "%(%a %d %b, week: %W)T\n" $c

  Thank you.

Comment: .1: crontab use `%` for *end of command* tab, please rtfm: `man -Pless\ +/% 5 crontab`

Comment: .1b: [tag:shell] (and [tag:bash]) use space to split arguments on input line. `date -d 2016-1-4\ 10:06 +%s` could by written: `date -d '2016-1-4 10:06' +%s`.

Comment: .2: syntax `a=$(cmd args)` will execute `cmd` with arguments `args` and store stantard output to variable `$a`. Syntax `b=$((3*5))` will compute (integer math) and store result to variable `$b`.

Comment: .2b: `printf "%(%a %d %b, %T)T\n" -1` will print current date and time. With an integer number in place of `-1`, this will print time on *`1st january 1970 + number seconds`*

Comment: Hi, Hauri, thanks your detail explanation :), it's cool and elegant!

Comment: You seem to be new user on SE. Please instead of `thanks' click on *upvote* and/or *accept* button (on answer, but on comments too ;)